# How to handle calling instance method in a constructor?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether

Is it possible to call (or schedule a call) to class method in constructor?

```
contract Foo
   constructor() {
      owner = msg.sender;
      this.setUp()
   }
   setUp() {
     // run some setup code
   }
```

I understand (unlike Javascript) that you can't call instance methods in constructor to initialize the state, or with specific libraries where you can 'hook' into some lifecycle method.

With Solidity, is there a recommended pattern for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to call non-external functions.

```
contract Foo {
    uint256 public x;
    
    constructor(uint256 y) public {
        setUp(y);
    }
    
    function setUp(uint256 w) public {
        x = w;
    }
}
```

If you use `this.setUp()` it will not work, similarly if the function setUp was declared external. The reason is because the contract's bytecode isn't deployed to the blockchain until the constructor has finished.